# How to set a time limit for ServerSocket to wait for the Client Socket to get connected

Tags: java, sockets, networking, timer, timertask

I am programming in  java using Sockets and facing this below metioned issue.

I programmed a Server program which sends a plain text to the client side.When I start the server the server program waits for a long time for the client socket to get connected.But i want the server program to wait only for a specified time say 5 minutes and then report the user that the Client is not connected within the Specified time.
I am unable to understand how to implement it.I have gone through Timer and TimerTask classes but its a bit confusing.

Answer (score 5):

Use [ServerSocket.setSoTimeout(int timeOut)](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) to wait for the client. Set it to `0` if you need to wait infinitely.

Note: Java doc says:

> The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to
>   have effect.

Comment: Yes I had also gone through the timeout concept but in this case the server socket itself will block the client.To illustrate say I have opened Server program and i want server to wait for Client for say 5 minutes.But within 5 minutes if client program is started then it has to get connected.If I set timeout to 5 minutes then in this case the client doesnt get connected untill 5 minutes have been finished which is completely complementary to my need.

Comment: @Intriguing You don't know what you're talking about. Setting a timeout does not introduce another delay. I suggest you try it before committing yourself further to this absurd proposition.

Comment: i have set `ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(2000);ss.setSoTimeout(30000);ss.accept(); `.Now when i first run the server program and next Client program, the server refuses the connection for 30 seconds.After that time the connection is established.But My need is that the server waits for the client for 2 minutes and then when the time is finished then server should not connect to client.

Answer (score 1):

As java API doc describes 'Socket.accept()':
Throws:
IOException - if an I/O error occurs when waiting for a connection.
SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkAccept method doesn't allow the operation.
**SocketTimeoutException - if a timeout was previously set with setSoTimeout and the timeout has been reached.**

See
[Java API Doc Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29)